# Order of $h$ is equal to the order of $ghg^{-1}$ for all $g , h \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that $o(h)$ is equal to $o(ghg^{-1})$ for all $g , h \in G$.

My attempt.

Let $m = o(h)$ and $d = o(ghg^{-1})$. Then it follows that $m$ is the smallest such integer such that $h^m = 1$ and $d$ is the smallest such integer such that $(ghg^{-1})^d$ = 1.

Consider $(ghg^{-1})^m$, then $(ghg^{-1})^m$ = $gh^mg^{-1} = gg^{-1} = 1$. Hence $d$ divides $m$. (1)

Now consider $h^d$. Since $d$ divides $m$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $m = nd$. Hence $h^d = h^ \frac{m}{n}$ = $(h^m)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ = $1^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$. Hence $m$ divides $d$. (2)

Therefore by (1) and (2) we get that $d = m$.

Can someone tell me if this is correct?

Comment: Umm... what is $G$?  You should explain much more about your symbols and the problem if you want help.

Comment: Sorry, G is just an arbitrary group.

Comment: also $o(h)$ is the order of $h$ and $o(ghg^{-1})$ is the order of $ghg^{-1}$.

Comment: You probably also want $G$ to be a finite group here, or some assumption on the order of $h$. But otherwise your proof is correct.

Comment: In a group $G$ you can not say $h^{\frac{1}{n}}$. This symbol does not make sense in this context. Try to this: $(ghg^{-1})^d = 1$, then $m$ divides $d$.

Comment: oh yes $G$ should be finite.

Comment: how does $(ghg^{-1})^d = 1$ imply that $m$ divides $d$?

Comment: @nhmwhhxx You don't need finite group or other assumptions: what you are doing is apply the conjugation by $g$ that is an automorphism

Comment: You want the assumption that the order of $h$ is finite. In these types of exercises, it's almost always in the context of finite groups.

Comment: @JordanReed $(ghg^{-1})^d = gh^dg^{-1}=1$. Left multiplication by $g^{-1}$, and right multiplication by $g$ and you obtain $h^d=1$, so $d|o(h)=m$

Comment: I see! thank you

Comment: @nhmwhhxx Well, I don't see why we have to add an useless hypotesis. In order to learn maths it seems useful to understand the reason why things works and the question if the statement holds for not finite group goes in this direction

Comment: Disagreement in how to learn, sure. In any case, the OP's question has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

$i_g:G\to G$ given by $i_g(h)=ghg^{-1}\,,\forall h\in G$,  is an automorphism for each $g\in G$.  A so-called *inner automorphism*.  As such, it preserves the orders of elements.

Answer (score 1):

I claim $h^m = e$ if and only if $(ghg^{-1})^m = e$

$\implies$ $(ghg^{-1})^m = gh^mg^{-1} = gg^{-1} = e$

$\impliedby$  $(ghg^{-1})^m = gh^mg^{-1} = e$. Multiplying on the right by $g$ and on the left by $g^{-1}$ gives $g^{-1}gh^mg^{-1}g = g^{-1}g$, so $h^m = e$ as desired.

This tells us that the set of $m$'s that make $h^m$ and $(ghg^{-1})^m$ the identity are exactly the same. In particular, this means they have the same least element, meaning $h$ and $(ghg^{-1})$ have the same order